# Move Horizental ScrollBar or a ListBox with a button in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, horizontal-scrolling

I am creating a winforms application in visual studio 2017, I am populating the list box using a List.

I set the multicolumn property to true. Since I have lots of strings in my list, there is a horizontal scrollbar appearing at the bottom of the box.

The application I am creating should be working on a tablet, so therefore the scroll bar is not easy to navigate using fingers.

My question is, is there a way to be able to control this scrollbar using a button ?

Comment: You try to set the [`Topindex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.topindex(v=vs.110).aspx) - To find the last visible index you can use `IndexFromPoint(lb.Width - w, lb.Height - h)` with `w` and `h` large enough to not hit the scrollbars.. `int h = SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarHeight - 18;`

Comment: in "lb.Width - w", what do I assign the w to ?

Comment: Just a small number, enough to be larger that the border; try 10!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send [`WM_HSCROLL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787575%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) message to the `ListBox` to scroll it. To do so, you should first get the scroll position by calling [`GetScrollInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787583(v=vs.85).aspx) methods.

The following code, scrolls the `ListBox`, 1 column to the right:

```
var info = new SCROLLINFO() { fMask = ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL };
GetScrollInfo(listBox1.Handle, SBOrientation.SB_HORZ, ref info);
var wparam = ((uint)(info.nPos + 1) << 16) | (SB_THUMBPOSITION & 0xffff);
SendMessage(listBox1.Handle, WM_HSCROLL, wparam, 0);
```

To scroll one column to the left, use  `info.nPos - 1`.

[image]

Here are the declarations which you need:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg,
    uint wParam, uint lParam);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SCROLLINFO {
    public uint cbSize;
    public ScrollInfoMask fMask;
    public int nMin;
    public int nMax;
    public uint nPage;
    public int nPos;
    public int nTrackPos;
}

public enum ScrollInfoMask : uint {
    SIF_RANGE = 0x1,
    SIF_PAGE = 0x2,
    SIF_POS = 0x4,
    SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x8,
    SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,
    SIF_ALL = (SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS),
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hwnd, 
    SBOrientation fnBar, ref SCROLLINFO lpsi);

public enum SBOrientation : int {
    SB_HORZ = 0x0,
    SB_VERT = 0x1,
}

const uint WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114;
const uint SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible to control the behavior you are expecting with the help of `Buttons`.

[image]

To move from right to left -

```
private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int visibleItemsInColumn = listBox1.ClientSize.Height / listBox1.ItemHeight; //No of items in each column. In this case - 5
    listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.TopIndex - visibleItemsInColumn;

}
```

To move from left to right -

```
private void btnRight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int visibleItemsInColumn = listBox1.ClientSize.Height / listBox1.ItemHeight;
    listBox1.TopIndex = listBox1.TopIndex + visibleItemsInColumn;
}
```

> What it actually does is every time you click on button, It
>   increases/decreases the TopIndex by the total elements per columns. So
>   on each clicks, you move one column either left or right.

Comment: @OmarAlMadani Unfortrunately you can select just one answer as accepted. But as soon as you gained enough reputation (15), you can upvote useful posts including the accepted answer.